# Plot, sampling, and why it does not display for some ranges

Tags: plotting, sampling

The following gives an empty plot on V12 under Windows 10:

```
f[x_, n_] := Piecewise[{{1, n < x < n + 1}, {0, True}}]
Plot[f[x, 7], {x, -30, 30 }, PlotRange -> {All, {-1, 1}}, Exclusions -> None]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Changing the range to make it little smaller, now shows it as:

```
Plot[f[x, 7], {x, -20, 20 }, PlotRange -> {All, {-1, 1}}, Exclusions -> None]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Also increasing Plot points and using the longer range, it now shows as:

```
Plot[f[x, 7], {x, -30, 30 }, PlotRange -> {All, {-1, 1}},
 Exclusions -> None, PlotPoints -> 20]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

OK, so I thought I needed more PlotPoints and that was all. But changing `f[x, 7]` to `f[x,8]` now shows it using the longer range and without changing the `PlotPints`:

```
Plot[f[x, 8], {x, -30, 30 }, PlotRange -> {All, {-1, 1}}, Exclusions -> None]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So there must be something else. It can't be the `PlotPoints`. Why would `f[x, 7]` need more points than `f[x,8]`?

The function only generates this:

```
Table[f[x, 7], {x, 7, 8, .1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Table[f[x, 8], {x, 8, 9, .1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

BTW, this has nothing to do with odd or even numbers. It seems random. For example,

```
Plot[f[x, 2], {x, -30, 30}, PlotRange -> {All, {-1, 1}}, Exclusions -> None]
```

It also gives an empty plot.

The sampling algorithm for `Plot` seems to miss all the points from `f[x, 7]`, but not from `f[x, 8]`. Why is that?

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/182993/1871 There should be more.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your plots aren't empty: they have a line along the x axis.

`Plot` uses `PlotPoints -> 50` by default, and since you go from -30 to 30, there will be some $n$ to $n+1$ intervals that don't get sampled:

```
In[66]:= Reap[
 Plot[x, {x, -30, 30}, MaxRecursion -> 0, 
   EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[x]];]

Out[66]= {Null, {{-30., -28.8223, -27.5455, -26.3533, -25.1845, \
-23.9167, -22.7335, -21.4512, -20.1922, -19.0179, -17.7446, -16.5558, \
-15.3904, -14.126, -12.9462, -11.6673, -10.4118, -9.24087, -7.97091, \
-6.78556, -5.50115, -4.24013, -3.06371, -1.78823, -0.597365, 0.570117,
    1.83666, 3.0186, 4.2996, 5.55721, 6.73021, 8.00228, 9.18974, 
   10.3538, 11.6169, 12.7955, 14.0731, 15.266, 16.4356, 17.7043, 
   18.8883, 20.1714, 21.4312, 22.6063, 23.8804, 25.07, 26.2362, 
   27.5014, 28.6821, 30.}}}
```

7 to 8, corresponding to `f[x, 7]` is one such interval.  Since we don't sample between those values, we never see `f[x,7] == 1` and the resulting plot is zero everywhere.

Comment: But this does not really explain why it shows the pulse when using other values of `n` for same range and same plot points? For example `f[x, 2]` it misses it, but `f[x, 8]` it does not. Same range.  So is it hit and miss type of thing? ps. I know the plot is not empty, (I see the line y=0 there) I was lazy :) and just meant the pulse itself is not showing. I should be more clear.

Comment: @Nasser Essentially, you see the pulse if the initial set of sampling points of `Plot` contains the pulse (if not, `Plot` has no reason to increase the sampling). If you look at the sampled points, you'll see that there are no points in $[2,3],[7,8],[13,14],[19,20],[24,25],[29,30]$, so if the pulse is in any of those intervals, `Plot` will miss it, otherwise it will find it

Answer (score 6):

Brett's answer explains the *why*.

To force sampling at specified points you can use an undocumented form of `PlotPoints` ([see this answer by Ullrich Neumann](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/200046/125)) :

```
f[x_, n_] := Piecewise[{{1, n < x < n + 1}, {0, True}}]

Plot[f[x, 7], {x, -30, 30}, 
  PlotPoints -> {50, {7}}, 
  PlotStyle -> CapForm["Butt"],
  Axes -> False, Frame -> True, 
  PlotRange -> {-1, 1}, 
  PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.05]]
```

[image]

Add `Exclusions -> None` to get the vertical portions:

[image]