# How to make a jump point show up in a plot of $\lfloor\sin(x)\rfloor$?

Tags: plotting

I tried Wolfram Mathematica, but could not pinpoint an answer.
I tried to plot the function: `f: x-> Floor[Sin[x]]`, but the graph is not even making room in the axis for the only dots of values equal to "1".

These points are only those of `x`'s values equal to any positive integer multiple of Pi/2, where `Floor[1]` is 1.
The plot command I used is this, just as it should be:

`Plot[(Floor@*Sin)[x], {x, -Pi, Pi}]`

[image]

Around `x=Pi/2` there were no accurate plotting of the case `x=Pi/2`.
When I adjusted the command to:
`Plot[(Floor@*Sin)[x], {x, (Pi - 0.000001)/2, (Pi + 0.000001)/2}]` Then the plot did jump to to the case `f(x)=f(Pi/2)=1` as it should:

[image]

Is there a way to make the plot jump accordingly in other similar cases? After all this was a significant jump of one unit.

Options like `PlotRange->All`, `Exclusions->None` or `ExclusionsStyle->Red` did not bring the missing dot back.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, this is due to sampling. I've had this problem before [Plot, sampling, and why it does not display for some ranges](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/207091/plot-sampling-and-why-it-does-not-display-for-some-ranges)

Another option might be to consider `DiscretePlot`?

```
f[n_] := (Floor@*Sin)[n*Pi/20]
DiscretePlot[f[n], {n, -20, 20}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you do not want to see the vertical lines

```
 DiscretePlot[f[n], {n, -20, 20}, Filling -> None]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the undocumented form `PlotPoints -> {n, {pt1, pt2, ...}}` to force sampling at `{pt1, pt2, ...}`:

```
 Plot[(Floor@*Sin)[x], {x, -Pi, Pi}, 
   Exclusions -> None, 
   PlotPoints -> {100, {Pi/2}}, 
   Frame -> True, Axes -> False]
```

[image]

**Note:** on this undocumented form of `PlotPoints` see [this answer by Ulrich Neumann.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/200046/125)